# How to add a div when clicking a button in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need to add the following div structure when i click button at every time?
I need to generate the following whole div structure at every time of clicking the button using jquery.

```
<div class="module_holder">
<div class="module_item">
<img src="images/i-5.png" alt="Sweep Stakes"><br>sendSMS
</div>
</div>
```

help me.

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need a container div that you can insert it into:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Then you can use the append() method of jquery:

```
$("#somebutton").click(function () {
  $("#container").append('<div class="module_holder"><div class="module_item"><img src="images/i-5.png" alt="Sweep Stakes"><br>sendSMS</div></div>');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this out http://jsfiddle.net/4dEsJ/1/ I'm sure there are better ways of creating the element, but if the structure and content remains the same, this works!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$('#button_id').click(function() {

    var structure = $('<div class="module_holder"><div class="module_item"><img src="images/i-5.png" alt="Sweep Stakes" /><br />sendSMS</div></div>');
   $('#whatever').append(structure); 

});
```