# how to add new text box when the button is clicked in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to add new div that included 4 textboxes when the add button is clicked. I have to do this for 3 times.
 The problem is that I can only make for the first time, that is: I don't know how to increase ID. I'm using jQuery fadeIn effect. 
I've found some useful answers, but I can't use them to solve my problem. The closest answer that I have found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678044/how-to-add-a-div-when-clicking-a-button-in-jquery), but that one is for every time. What I want is just for 3 times. My reference is [here](http://w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadein) and this is also only one time.
 How can I repeat it for 3 times?

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: And wt abt 4th click...if user clicks 4 th time then.

Comment: cant u use one global variable and increment it every time u add dynamic elemets and check if its equal to 3

Comment: My code is too long to comment coz of that 4 div with 4 textboxes. @Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You looking for something like this:

*Demo*: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/r6A7f/2/**

*Markup*:

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Add" />
<div id="wrap"></div>
```

*JS*:

```
var i = 1; // counter to track number of divs
$("#btn").click(function () {
    if (i < 4) { // check if three divs have been created

        // create a div and use index for id
        var $d = $("<div />", {
            id: "d" + i,
            class: 'container'
        });

        // loop for creating 4 inputs
        for (n = 1; n < 5; n++) {
            // create an input and use index for id
            var $i = $("<input />", {
                type: "text",
                id: "i" + n,
                placeholder: "i" + n
            });

            // append the input to the div
            $d.append($i);
        }
        // append the div to the wrapper
        $('#wrap').append($d);

        // increment the index for div creation
        i++;
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh Yes , Dear ! I markup your answer ^_^ Thanks indeed!!!!! comments make ur answer perfect. Thx !! Thx!!

Answer (score 2):

do:

```
var counter = 1;
$("#addBtn").click(function () {
    if(counter <= 4) {
    var $input = $("<input />", {
        type: "text",
        id: "input_" + (counter),
        name: "some_name",
        value: ""
    });
  $("#container").append($input);
    counter++;
    }
});
```

Demo :: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6A7f/)

Comment: Thanks Sudhir. I'll try ^_^ Your answer is really useful for me ;)

Comment: You can add a class (for example, "appendedInput") to newly generated input and get "counter" by "$("#container").children(".appendedInput").length;". I slightly modified Sudhir's demo, it is here: http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/5Rsrr/